# Native iOS app to interface with javascript based web service

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I am writing iOS native client for a service that is written in Javascript. I have no prior experience with Javascript and URL session with javascript login, but assume I would be using the new JavascriptCore Framework Objective-C API for working with objects and functions. How can I authenticate to start the URL Session if the login functionality is in the .js file?

I have this info:

```
Javascript file: js/Applications/Html/HtmlLogin.js
WebService: /WebServices/Service.asmx/
Function: LoginUser
CodeFile: CallWeb.Membership.User
Function: GetUser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like your service is written in Javascript. Javascript is a client side scripting language (embedded in HTML). It looks like your service is written in .Net (based on the ".asmx" extension).

If you really want to continue to use javascript as the client code within the iOS app, I recommend you just do it as HTML in an embedded UIWebView. However, this might have a sub-par user experience. If you want to do it as a true native app, you need to figure out how the javascript is interacting with the web service, but reimplement it in Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree the web service is based on .Net. Currently the service has a Javascript based reporting logic, so when a user interacts with the service, javascript retrieves the data and can do some filtering in the web browser. I was asked to interface with this javascript model/logic in a native iOS app. I looked into the JavascriptCore framework and assumed I would be able to interact with the javascript code to get data and then handle iOS Views and Controllers part. But how can I authenticate to the service now? Currently the login is behind a button on the page with .js

Comment: Do you mean that the web service is based on JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)? You can mimic exactly what a javascript request looks like with standard iOS network requests. I am not familiar with a way that a web service could require that it only be accessed by a specific language.

Comment: The web service returns XML and supports standard GET and POST methods, so I should be able to use these. But I am asked to handle some graphs and images and I suspect that these are generated at the client in the javascript code.